# Can alimentary packaging film be used to make a Fabry-Perot interferometer?

Tags: optics, interferometry

An alimentary packaging film consists on a thin plastic layer. If we put two of this films one on the other, could this acts as a [Fabry-Perot interferometer](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/fabry.html)? (I don't have the appropriate material at home to try and it doesn't work with incoherent light).

As we don't usually see a "rainbow" on a such film of plastic, I was wondering if this was related to the non-conducting properties of it (but glass doesn't conduct too). What else could it be?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.   You might see a rainbow on a piece of plastic under some tension (to keep in flat) when viewed at an appropriate angle.  The two surfaces of the sheet are the reflective layers -- you don't need two layers of plastic.   But you'll only see the rainbow when the optical thickness of the light's path between the reflective layers (optical thickness = (actual thickness)/n ) is on the order of a wavelength.  The rainbow effect occurs because the wavelength at which constructive interference occurs changes with viewing angle-- essentially change in path length.

Comment: Thus you say that it should be possible with a film of thickness 10 $\mu m$ (the thiner I found). (The spectrum would not be as clearly separated as with a $1 \mu m$ film, but we should see something...